# Improve condition code

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I've the following code

```
var oDataEn = aData[0][aProperties[0].split('/')[0]];
if (!(oDataEn != null && oDataEn.results && oDataEn.results.length > 0)) {
    ...
    else

...
```

This is working **OK** except when

```
aData[0] = 'undefined'
```

my question is if there  a **better** way to write it instead of just adding before

```
 if(aData[0] != null)
  {
    var oDataEn = aData[0][aProperties[0].split('/')[0]];
  }
```

I dont want to have two if's if possible...

Comment: would you like to skip if aData[0] is undefined?

Comment: I think you have a typo in `aData[0] = 'undfiend'` it should have been `undefined`

Comment: @mplungjan - Thanks but it failed before with aData[0] which is undifiend...

Comment: you should also consider that a shorter code doesn't mean a better code :) you may have a shorter code but not the best and not in most optimized way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with a ternary - I assume aData[0] may be falsy (null, undefined, 0 or ""):

```
var oDataEn = aData[0]?aData[0][aProperties[0].split('/')[0]]:null;
if (oDataEn && oDataEn.results && oDataEn.results.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      if(aData[0] === undefined){}
```

is the best way so far I know.

As per your comment

```
     if(typeof aData[0] != 'undefined' /*&& other if statements*/){}
```

So it will not process if it is undefined.

Comment: Thanks but I mean to write it better for the all context not just the if I've added in the end of the question :)( I mean take a look at the all statement with the first and the second if statment...)

Comment: if I added the second if that I post "of just adding before.." I've two if statments...

Comment: you should write  "!==" when you use typeof :) though "!=" would work aswell

Comment: You can use a shorthand Conditional (ternary) Operator:

var oDataEn = aData[0] ? aData[0][aProperties[0].split('/')[0]] : null;

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @JustinOber yes he can :)))

Comment: @mplungjan almost a jinx moment

Answer (score 0):

By using ternary operator u can do this. Ternary operator will reduce the line of codes only.

```
    var oDataEn = aData[0] === undefined ? '' : aData[0][aProperties[0].split('/')[0]];
```